# custom workflow multiple user then last user is error

Tags: workflow, alfresco, activiti, bpmn

from link
https://ecmarchitect.com/alfresco-developer-series-tutorials/workflow/tutorial/tutorial.html

i've custom workflow multiple user like ParallelReview. Workflow can start and assign but last people have error
[image: image error]

training.bpmn20.xml
[image: bpmn20]

[Training.bpmn20.xml](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XNfRNDCG-Xq66LREYzWhFR1CI7J1j3YN/view?usp=sharing)

[scWorkflowModel.xml](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1t7EpoSQMcu2ir3SyMELm90kvjW6pc_et/view)

[log.txt](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1M3MDO1XkAbcOEyPo4jVNd-D_k9tvFOBe/view)

Please help me

Thank you

I'm sorry for my bad language .

Comment: At a guess I'd say this is the key line from your error log: `Exception while invoking TaskListener: Exception while invoking TaskListener: 04100042 Failed to execute supplied script: missing ) after argument list (AlfrescoJS#6)` - fix your scripts to be valid

Comment: `if(task.getVariableLocal('scwf_reviewOutcome') == 'Acknowledge' }) {`
                                
check your script, remove the `}`